# Webdriver access data-interchange element

Tags: java, groovy, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've a quick question...well what I hope will be a quick questions.

I have a div element which looks like the following:

```
<div class="slideshow-image" data-thumb-index="0" data-interchange="
                        [//someURL/5/568/1_40.jpg, (default)],
                        [//someURL/5/568/1_40.jpg, (small)],
                        [//someURL/5/568/1_70.jpg, (medium)],
                        [//someURL/5/568/1_base.jpg, (large)]
                    " data-uuid="interchange-i9a0pkp20" style="min-height: 527px; background-image: url(http://someURL/5/568/1_base.jpg);">
                <div class="pageheader-overlay"></div></div>
```

Now through webdriver I want to get each of the URL's in the data-interchange. However I've zero idea how to get this out...can anyone out there help?

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example based on the following conditions:

1) `div` will be searched by its `classname`

2) the result string is split into pieces by the comma

3) the split strings are checked if they end with "jpg" - if so, some formatting and trimming is made

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Selenium2Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    // local test URL
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080");

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("slideshow-image"));

    String attribute = element.getAttribute("data-interchange");
    String[] urls = attribute.split(",");

    for (String url : urls) {
      if (url.endsWith("jpg")) {
        System.out.println("URL Info: " + url.replace("[", "").trim());
      }
    }

    // Close the browser
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah that's what I was thinking of doing...however i was hoping there was some cleaner way of getting the data-interchange values directly from webdriver :)

Comment: Since the values itself are only a String for the WebDriver it makes it hard to get it in a cleaner way. Maybe the string parsing/formatting can be improved.

Comment: Yup agree makes it hard to get in a nice clean way.

Comment: Thanks for the help swinkler...really appreciate it!